# Python: solve a linear system Ax=b, but only first element of the solution is needed and A is a sparse matrix

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

At the moment I am trying to make my program more efficient. I have to solve a linear system Ax=b. But A has quite a lot of zero entries, so that I used `scipy.sparse.lil_matrix` to consume less memory, because A is a 80k by 80k matrix or more.

Now I am trying to solve the system more efficiently, since I only need the first element of the solution. By now I have used the following: `np.linalg.solve(A, b)[0]` or `sp.sparse.linalg.spsolve(A, b)[0]`

Is there any other solution to that? I have thought about applying Cramer's rule, but that would need the determinant.

Comment: I suspect that you will have to solve the whole system unless you can figure out a way to decouple it. That's sort of the whole thing with linear systems.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't now how to decouple the system

Comment: Then you will in fact have to solve the whole system. You might be able to get away with having to do only a one-way reduction, since you need just one element, but you might have to code up the solver yourself then, or at least modify the existing on heavily.

Comment: Well I do not think that would speed up the whole thing :D I am pretty sure that my programming skills are too low to beat an existing solver. But thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: I don't mean code your own solver from scratch. I mean take the code of the existing one, and cut out the second half once you understand how.

Comment: Yes, mathematically this is possible. Assuming your matrix is square but otherwise not remarkable, the solver will likely calculate `A`'s (sparse) LU decomposition per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Solving_linear_equations and if you draw it out, you'll see that it's trivial to solve for the first (or last, depending on whether the triangle is upper or lower) unknown. It's unlikely but possible that the cost of the triangular solve is comparable to the cost of the LU factorization, in which case you can get the first element of the solution faster than solving them all.

Comment: Can you tell us if `A` is indeed square, and if it's symmetric or any other features about it? Can you also post the runtimes of `scipy.sparse.linalg.factorized(A)` versus `sp.sparse.linalg.spsolve(A, b)` and `np.linalg.solve(A, b)` (for the same `A`)? If you can share your sparse `A` that'd be even better, since the answer will depend on `A`.